# Run program x minutes after finishing

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scheduling

My question is kinda related to a cron job I think, but I'm not entirely sure.

Say I have a script (`/home/me/myscript.sh`) that does something, that can take an indeterminate amount of time to finish, say a range of between 10 minutes to an hour. What I want, is for the script to run, and when it finishes, run again in an hour. Is there any kind of "scheduler" or something that I could use to achieve this? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Your answer is in http://serverfault.com/questions/248305/running-cron-every-10-minutes. But if your program takes long time before finishing you can also use `at now+10min` at the end of your script. This is not safe though, since if the script crashes or the system is restarted and the time of the next execution is exceeded the script won't run again unless you launch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron` sounds unsuitable for this; an hour after the completion of the previous run could either be done via a `while` loop

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
    some_job_that_takes_a_while
    sleep 3600
done
```

or by scheduling the next run in one hour via `at(1)` at the end of the job.

```
$ cat atat
#!/bin/sh
echo running the job
echo $HOME/atat | at now + 1 hours
$ ./atat
running the job
job 4 at 2015-09-30 17:00
$ date
Wed Sep 30 16:00:19 UTC 2015
$
```

There may need to be sanity checks or a `timeout` on the job, in the event it gets stuck and thus no subsequent jobs run until someone manually kills it and restarts things.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to tell cron to do it. Just use this as the command that cron will run:

```
/home/me/myscript.sh; sleep 1h; /home/me/myscript.sh
```

If your `sleep` does not support the `h` suffix, use `sleep 3600` instead.

Alternatively, write a wrapper script, call it `wrapper.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/home/me/myscript.sh
sleep 1h 
/home/me/myscript.sh
```

And run that with cron.

Comment: Would that not double run the script when It loops back around?

Comment: @TomHart no, that's the wrapper script. You will run `wrapper.sh` with `cron` and it will launch `myscript.sh` twice. `wrapper.sh` will only run once.

Comment: @ring0 ouch, thanks, don't know what I was thinking there.